# Import CSV file using pandas and retain column headings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file with the following data

```
firstName,lastName,email,phoneNumber
John,Doe,john@doe.com,0123456789
Jane,Doe,jane@doe.com,9876543210
James,Bond,james.bond@mi6.co.uk,0612345678
```

I would like to store it in a python dictionary. I'm using pandas to try to import it and retain the file headers for each column.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=',')
dicts = df.to_dict().values()
print(dicts)
```

This outputs

```
dict_values([{0: 'John', 1: 'Jane', 2: 'James'}, {0: 'Doe', 1: 'Doe', 2: 'Bond'}, {0: 'john@doe.com', 1: 'jane@doe.com', 2: 'james.bond@mi6.co.uk'}, {0: 123456789, 1: 9876543210, 2: 612345678}])
```

Which does not appear to retain the headers 'firstName,lastName,email,phoneNumber'

```
 print ("dict['Name']: ", dict['firstName'])
 TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want just `to_dict`:

```
In[92]:
df.to_dict()

Out[92]: 
{'email': {0: 'john@doe.com', 1: 'jane@doe.com', 2: 'james.bond@mi6.co.uk'},
 'firstName': {0: 'John', 1: 'Jane', 2: 'James'},
 'lastName': {0: 'Doe', 1: 'Doe', 2: 'Bond'},
 'phoneNumber': {0: 123456789, 1: 9876543210, 2: 612345678}}
```

e.g.:

```
In[93]:
d = df.to_dict()
d['email']

Out[93]: {0: 'john@doe.com', 1: 'jane@doe.com', 2: 'james.bond@mi6.co.uk'}
```

by calling `.values` this returns a numpy value array, this has no column labels, just the index labels